# SF Retag Request: [Exchange-Server] -> [Exchange] or the other way

Tags: support, retag-request

There are currently around 400 questions tagged Exchange, and 16 tagged Exchange-Server. Obviously we don't need both, and I would say we get rid of Exchange-Server as there are less questions.

That said, we do have a windows-server tag for generic questions about Windows Server, so maybe we should get rid of the Exchange tag and use Exchange-Server for non version specific Exchange questions.

Any thoughts on what's best, and can a Mod please do it.

Comment: is there any ambiguity in any of the [exchange] tags or are they all about the MS product?  if there's any possible ambiguity i'd go with the more specific [exchange-server] or even [ms-exchange] (this is what SU does with the ambiguous [access], for example).

Comment: So far they all seem to be about MS Exchange

Answer (score 3):

Retag completed.

Comment: Thanks Sam! Sorry, I didn't see this post until now. Feel free to contact me (just flag a question) for other tag-related jobs.

Comment: @splattne no problem, there weren't many tags so I figured I may as well do it myself